# Link PIWIK statistics to user table in a extranet

Tags: matomo

I have a extranet that uses PIWIK to monitor visit statistics. I have enabled User ID to monitor unique visits. My question is if there a way to link this User Id in PIWIK to my user table in my extranet ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you would need to send the User ID from your extranet to Piwik with the `setUserId` option discussed [in the docs](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#user-id).

If you're using Javascript: before you track the pageview, set the user ID with:

```
_paq.push(['setUserId', 'USER_ID_HERE']);
```

When you look at the Visitor Log, you'll see the extranet user ID for any authenticated users that had the variable set.